# codeigniter : record the url of an error log

Tags: codeigniter, logging, uri, codeigniter-2

Sometimes it can be hard to diagnose problems that occurs in a medium / big codeIgniter application. When we don't know how the user accessed to a ressource it can be hard to reproduce. Here's a very handy script.

Answer (score 1):

Script provided by  ["kirill" in a blog posted on "key2market.com"](http://www.key2market.com/2010/09/customising-error-logging-with-codeigniter-2-0/)

It records the error, the URI and the posted data into you log file. If your application has lots of errors, that script may slow your server.

- Just create file "[CI]application/core/MY_Exceptions.php"
- Copy/pastethe following script :

## begin

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions{

    /**
    * Constructor
    *
    */
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
    * Exception Logger
    *
    * This function logs PHP generated error messages
    *
    */
    function log_exception($severity, $message, $filepath, $line)
    {
        $severity = ( ! isset($this->levels[$severity])) ? $severity : $this->levels[$severity];
        $message = 'Severity: '.$severity.' –> '.$message. ' '.$filepath.' '.$line.' [URI='.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].']';

        if( !empty($_POST) ){
            $message .= 'POST: ';
            foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
                $message .= $key.' => '.$value;
            }
        }
        log_message('error', $message, TRUE);
    }

}
// END Exceptions Class

/* End of file Exceptions.php */
/* Location: ./ci_app/core/Exceptions.php */
```

## end